# How to detect Permission deletion in bigquery resource

Tags: google-bigquery

Unable to find audit log on removing bigquery table permission. I could find only bigquery set Iam policy log in the cloud log but doesnt have remove iam policy in audit log. Any help on auditing on removing the user permission on bigquery tables?

Comment: Please more clarify your question.

Answer (score 0):

`setIamPolicy` is the method used for all IAM policy changes, includes those that remove user bindings.

If User A removes a binding for User B, they are simply posting a new policy document that excludes User B; the logs will only show the new policy and won't have information about the diff.

**Old Policy**

```yaml
bindings:
- members:
   - user:user-a@acme.com
   - user:user-b@acme.com
   role: roles/roles/bigquery.dataOwner
```

**New Policy**

```yaml
bindings:
- members:
   - user:user-a@acme.com
   role: roles/roles/bigquery.dataOwner
```

To see IAM removal events, you'll have to query on `setIamPolicy` and evaluate all policy changes. If you'd like to track events where a *specific* user principal was removed from a policy altogether, you can use an `AND NOT` query to identify changes where a policy exclude specific users:

```
protoPayload.methodName="google.iam.v1.IAMPolicy.SetIamPolicy"
protoPayload.serviceName="bigquery.googleapis.com"
AND NOT protoPayload.serviceData.setIamPolicyRequest.policy.bindings.members="user:<USER TO AUDIT POLICY REMOVALS>"
```

One caveat to this approach: this filter will not pick up cases where a user is partially removed from a policy (e.g. only a single role was removed).